# Why googles analytics.js won't work in mobile webviews?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics.js

We recently wanted to switch from the old ga.js to the new analytics.js library. Everything worked great. No issues in any mobile or desktop browsers but we also have native Apps on Android and iPhone and sometimes want to display ads in a Webview. But somehow the tracking doesn't work anymore on both iPhone and Android.

When we went back using the ga.js again everything worked even the webviews. 
e.g.
`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'super_ad', 'clicked'])`

but the same with the new analytics.js `ga('send', 'event', 'super_ad', 'clicked')` won't work just for in app web views.

Is everyone having the same issues or has google just stopped the support for webviews?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No, we didn't make the switch because of the issue.

Comment: Did your webviews have javascript enabled? I believe my issue is because by default the webviews have javascript disabled

Comment: I think it is because GA needs the request to be sent from the domain if you are using js SDK.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the tracker, does your code look like this?

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'yoursite.com', { userId: youruid });
```